# extract part of a line before and after a string

Tags: linux, text-processing

example line:

```
04/07/2016 11:23:44 [8344] BDFDD123A Some Text Here (Word: ABD_ABDCD, Word: Word, Word: Word Word-ABCAbcAbc-HOSTNAME.DOMAINNAME.COM-ASDF).
```

I'd like to extract the "HOSTNAME.DOMAINNAME.COM-ASDF" part.

There is always a "-" before the "HOSTNAME" part and the line always ends with "." but not always ")."

It seems like if I could say for each line
1.) find the string ".COM" 
2.) then go back to the previous "-" and forward to the next "." and give me everything in between that would work... but I have no idea how to do that.

Normally I would try to split by some sort of separator but it's not the same number of separators for every line. any idea how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
grep -Po -- '-\K[^-]+\..*?(?=(?:\)|)\.$)' file.txt
```

- `-` matches a `-` and `\K` discards the match
- `[^-]+\..*?` matches the desired substring
- The zero width positive lookahead pattern `(?=(?:\)|)\.$)` ensures the match is followed by `).` or just `.` at the end of the line.

---

**Example:**

```
$ grep -Po -- '-\K[^-]+\..*?(?=(?:\)|)\.$)' <<<'04/07/2016 11:23:44 [8344] BDFDD123A Some Text Here (Word: ABD_ABDCD, Word: Word, Word: Word Word-ABCAbcAbc-HOSTNAME.DOMAINNAME.COM-ASDF).'
HOSTNAME.DOMAINNAME.COM-ASDF
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the -ASDF part then

```
sed -E 's/.*-(.*-[^)]*)\)?\.$/\1/'
```

If you don't care about the -ASDF part then it's simpler

```
sed 's/.*-\(.*\)-.*/\1/' x
```

This works by being "greedy" in the first `.*`